# C program strings

Tags: c

I run the following c program

```
char str[80] = "String";
printf("hello %s\n", str);
scanf("%s", str);
printf("%s\n", str);
scanf("%[ABCDEF]", str);
printf("hello %s\n", str);

return 0;
```

For some reason on line 5 when it is suppose to input from Pattern %[ABCDEF], the console simply prints previous string (input from line 3). Why is that so?

Comment: your str declaration does not make sense.  you can't update literal values like that.

Comment: You do know that `scanf` does return a value - perhaps worth checking

Comment: @OldProgrammer i was simply trying to see how the c program is behaving because i'm learing. So yeah, i got the answer from August Karlstorm

Comment: @DavidSchwartz if i correct it as scanf(" %[ABCDEF]", str); now string takes only characters specified between []

Comment: @EdHeal Yeah, i realised that just now. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats because the first *scanf* call doesn't read the newline character and the second call to *scanf* simply reads that newline character. To avoid this start the format string with a space like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[80] = "String";

    printf("hello %s\n", str);
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    scanf(" %[ABCDEF]", str);
    printf("hello %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

However, you also need to make sure that *str* doesn't overflow if the user inputs a string longer than 79 characters.